# sum of variable in parse PHP

Tags: php, parsing

i am trying to Sum of variable in loop Parse PHP frame, its working but not getting expected result, i expect 1+1 is 2 but getting 11 meand its print both the variable insted of doing sum,

my Code is

```
    function amount()
    {

      $ip=getUserIP();        

     $crat_item= new ParseQuery("Cart");
     $crat_item->EqualTo("ipAddress", $ip);
     $crat_item->each(function($object){
                 GLOBAL $sum;
                  $total=0;
                  $a=$object->get('quantity');
                  $prMSP=intval($a);
                  $fMSP=array('msp' => $prMSP);

                  $sum=array_sum($fMSP);

                   $total+=$sum; 

                   echo "$total"; 

                    });           
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're resetting your `$total` variable in the loop. So it's actually printing `1` & then `1` again, not `11`.

Modify it to do the following;

```
$total = 0; // define $total variable here..
$crat_item->each(function($object) {
    GLOBAL $sum;
    $a = $object->get('quantity');
    $prMSP = intval($a);
    $fMSP = array('msp' => $prMSP);

    $sum = array_sum($fMSP);

    $total+=$sum;
});

// now echo total
echo "$total";
```

<sup>*Notice how we've moved the variable instantiation out of the function? That's the stop it being "recreated" every time you loop over the data response. The same with your `echo` of the `$total`.*</sup>

Comment: thank  you very much, but there is aslo minor change u need to add is convert variable total in to GLOBAL underneeth

Comment: @PRAKASHKUMARPATEL It's your code so yeah! But a word of advice, steer clear of `global`'s, they cause no end of heartache. ;-P

Answer (score 0):

this is final answer for abobe question `function amount()
        {

```
      $ip=getUserIP(); 
      GLOBAL $total; 

      $total=0;      

     $crat_item= new ParseQuery("Cart");
     $crat_item->EqualTo("ipAddress", $ip);
     $crat_item->each(function($object){
                 GLOBAL $sum; 
                 GLOBAL $total; //convert it in global here
                 // $total=0;
                 // GLOBAL $sum;
            $a = $object->get('productMSP');
            $prMSP = intval($a);
            $fMSP = array('msp' => $prMSP);

            $sum = array_sum($fMSP);

            $total+=$sum; 



                    }); echo "$total";          
    }`
```